# Is there a difference in these two ways of rendering sprites?

Tags: libgdx

I use an OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer:

```
renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(world.getMap());
```

and I wonder if there is a differnce between this call:

```
renderer.getSpriteBatch().draw(sprite, sprite.getX(), sprite.getY());
```

and this:

```
sprite.draw(renderer.getSpriteBatch());
```

If there is a difference, what is it?

Comment: While there's no difference between the two, I do want to point out something for future reference: OrthogonalTiledMapRenderers have a SpriteBatch in the class, meaning that if you have a SpriteBatch to render everything and then you create a OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer to render your map, you'll come up with some pretty random rendering bugs. An easy fix is to instantiate the OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer like so: `OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer mapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map, alreadyExistingSpriteBatch);`

Comment: Sprite is a subclass of TextureRegion. I found this helpful when thinking about drawing Sprites.

Answer (score 2):

I found this in the libGDX source code, in class [Sprite.java](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.java)

```
public void draw (Batch batch) {
    batch.draw(texture, getVertices(), 0, SPRITE_SIZE);
}
```

So no, no difference. It shows Sprite.draw is only syntactic sugar for the longer version you posted.